# Can I implement Google Sign-in into a web app hosted on AWS S3?

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3, google-authentication

I implemented Google Sign in to my Angular application following this tutorial here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/ .
It worked fine on the localhost. Now I am trying to host my Angular application on an AWS S3 bucket. I allowed the the root url of the S3 bucket in the Google developer console. Google Sign in button is there but when ever I click I get the following error:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_request

Application: xx Demo

You can email the developer of this application at: ...

Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.

Request Details
openid.realm=
scope=email profile openid
response_type=permission
redirect_uri=storagerelay://http/s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com?id=auth...
ss_domain=http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
client_id=.....apps.googleusercontent.com
fetch_basic_profile=true
```

I found this post [here](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/04/21/s3-http-basic-auth.html). It says

> When using Amazon S3, though, it is not possible to protect your
>   website because the content is purely static. This means you can't
>   have a login page on the front end. With the service, you can either
>   make your objects either absolutely public — so that anyone can see
>   them online — or assign access rights to them — but only for users
>   connected through RESTful API.

Does this mean I can't use Google Sign in button if I host this application on S3 buckets?

I never deployed anything before. I'll really appreciate some insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement Google Sign in even though you host your website on S3. You will have to put some information publicly, such as the client token, but on the Google API Console you will restrict access to the API to only your domain.

When you say you allowed the root endpoint for your S3 Bucket in the Google API Console, are you talking about the actual bucket url or the URL that the bucket gives you when you allow Static Website Hosting? You should use the Static Website Hosting url.

Comment: @filipebaretto thanks for pointing out the urls. I just noticed what I did. I added the  S3 website endpoint as an authorized url in the Google developer console. But I kept opening the index file (actual_bucket_url/index.html) from the S3 bucket instead of going to the s3 website endpoint which is the static website hosting url when you enable the website hosting. Thanks very much. I'll accept your answer.